# What runes go well with Ahri?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm planning on buying runes (sooner of later), but I'm not really sure which to go with. I found [a guide on solomid](http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=34307-barph-ahri-build-guide#chap4) that is intended for Ahri. The rune setup they have is below:

[image]

The guide lists them too:

> - 9 Greater Seal of Scaling Ability Power
> - 4 Greater Glyph of Scaling Ability Power
> - 5 Greater Glyph of Magic Resist
> - 3 Greater Quintessence of Ability Power
> - 9 Greater Mark of Hybrid Penetration

Is this a good rune setup for me to aim for or should I be trying for something different?

Comment: Be careful with guides you find on the net. Do not blindly follow them. Not even my own answer -- I might have forgotten some special cases.

Comment: Why o WHY they gave her Hybrid Pen is beyond me. Armor pen is flat out useless for Ahri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just don't buy the 9 Greater Mark of Hybrid Penetration.**

It may be good, but if you're looking for runes, I'd advise you to buy runes which are great for a LOT of champions. Hybrid pen runes are only good for 2 or 3 champs. magic Penetration runes are much better for almost every other carry AP, and are not bad at all on Ahri.

Answer (score 2):

That setup is fine, in all honesty runes don't make *that* much of a difference in a match. Personally I run 2x Movement Speed Quints and 1x HP Quint, for the most part runes, masteries, and summoner spells are preferences.

If you plan on playing mid a lot it's always a good idea to invest on an MR page (although not really needed) for the more difficult match-ups like Veigar or LeBlanc.

Comment: keep in mind, that 30-50 ap flat on lvl 1 do make quite some difference.

Answer (score 2):

**Rune setup guidelines for AP carries, as of patch 3.8:**

- **Marks** : Magic Penetration. Period. Most of them do not deal enough physical damage to make Hybrid Penetration efficient.
- **Seals** : Armor or Scaling Health, depending on your lane opponent. Scaling Ability Power seals are NOT primary, thus less efficient. Even as an AP carry, you WILL benefit from defensive seals more than offensive ones.
- **Glyphs** : Magic Resist, Scaling Magic Resist or Scaling Ability Power.

  If your lane opponent is an AP carry like you, go for Magic Resist.

  If your lane opponent mostly deals physical damage, or if you do not fear his magical damage, go for Scaling Magic Resist.

  If your lane opponent mostly deals physical damage, and NOBODY deals significant magical damage in the enemy team, go for Scaling Ability Power, stack armor and swim in their tears.
- **Quints** : Ability Power. Even if Ahri has meh ratios, it will help you farm with your spells and improve your early game potential slightly. A few AP carries might benefit more from Movement Speed, such as Ryze ; but Ahri doesn't.